# Was Landau interested in the interpretations of quantum mechanics?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, quantum-mechanics, physicists, landau

I am interested in Lev Landau. I was trying to find what was his approach to the interpretation of quantum mechanics, I am unable to find any particular source were this is discussed.

Was he an advocate of any particular interpretation? or was he like Dirac that was purposely never interested in this problem? I hope there is some information about it.

Comment: In the early days Landau was concerned not with interpreting quantum mechanics but with overthrowing it for a new synthesis with relativity, see [Landau-Peierls](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01391513). As the prospect receded into "distant future" he became "purely practical", "*actively discouraged his students from embracing Bohr’s epistemological concerns*"; "*A student who knew Landau from 1951 onward testifies that he never heard his teacher discuss the foundations of quantum mechanics*", see [Hall, The Schooling of Lev Landau](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/591876).

Comment: It seems that he never wrote about interpretation.

Comment: It is discussed extensively in Landau-Lifschitz.

Comment: @dodd which one?

Comment: There is, for example, a volume on quantum optics.

Comment: @dodd does he talk about interpretations in the quantum optics volume?

Comment: @MauricoL The whole volume is about interpretation, as far as I remember (I studied that subject about 45 years ago, and, fortunately, forgot most of it) .

Comment: @user14095 there is no Landau-Lifshitz book on quantum optics

Comment: @Mauricio My reading of "Volume III" of his text book is that he suggests a kind of [Objective Collaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics#Objective-collapse_theories) But I might me wrong.

Comment: @RaphaelJ.F.Berger could you provide a quote?

Comment: @Mauricio Landau L.D., Lifshitz E.M. - Quantum mechanics. non-relativistic theory. Vol.3. -Pergamon (1991) pages 1-5 "objective collapse" is not mentioned as a term there but in my reading it's that effectively. At least the basic idea of it.